# Getting error while setting context path to url

Tags: java, jsp, contextpath

I am setting the context path in jsp page but it is showing error while running the jsp page.

as shown below.

```
<c:set var="path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<% urlName='<c:out value="${path}"/>/tran/handleTransactionResults.do'; %>
```

${path} is not showing the context path.

Comment: The runtime will simply not interprete the value you set for `urlName`, it's just a Java String. Does this page compile at all?

Comment: Then how. Some times it is working..and some times showing error page.

Comment: My understanding is that @nfechner solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use JSP tags within a scriptlet. Do it like this:

```
<c:set var="path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<% urlName= request.getAttribute("path") + "/tran/handleTransactionResults.do"; %>
```

Or even easier:

```
<% urlName= request.getContextPath() + "/tran/handleTransactionResults.do"; %>
```

If you simply want to output your path, you can use the `<%= %>` shortcut:

```
<%= request.getContextPath() + "/tran/handleTransactionResults.do"; %>
```

Comment: in your first scenario it is displaying for the link as `/dnweb/tran/null` getting an error.

But in Second Scenario request.getContextPath() it is displaying perfectly as `/dnweb`and working fine. 

and the last one you have given Expression. i did't tried it. Any way thanks.

It is working fine.